# How to make a Discord bot clear a specific channel's messages on a specified time interval and also on a command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to be able to clear all the messages in a **specific** discord channel at a specific time every day. I also want to manually be able to do this using a set command. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

edit: After thinking about it a bit more, I actually don't need the bot to clear on a time interval, only on command so don't worry about the time part.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! This is the place to go when you are truly stuck on a problem, but you did not provide any code in your question, so I must ask: have you tried anything yet? Have you looked at the docs to see how you might be able to do this? You need to do research and attempt to solve your problem, we aren't really here to just write parts of your bot for you. If you've tried something already, add that code to your question and ask why it isn't working. If not, look at the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org); if you are still stuck afterwards, then we can assist.

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please attempt to solve your problem before asking a question, and detail your attempts (providing code for what you tried) in the question if your attempts did not work out.

**Possible Solutions**

As for clearing a specific channel, there are *many* ways to do this. All you really needed to do was look at the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org) to find the answer. Two ways that you can achieve this are: `textChannel.bulkDelete()` or `textChannel.clone()`. Which option you choose to use really depends on how often you should be able to clear the channel(s). If you want to clear all of the messages in a channel, but that channel has messages that were sent 2 or more weeks ago, then the `bulkDelete()` option will not be able to clear all of the messages in that channel. If you want to be able to clear every message in the channel, regardless of how much time has passed, you'll want to go with the channel-cloning method. Note that the cloning method will require channel management perms, so if that's out of the question, you'll need to go with `bulkDelete()`.

**Example**

The following code uses the `clone()` method and is directly taken and modified from the code of one of my own discord bots (it can be found [here](https://github.com/Cannicide/scav-bot/blob/master/commands/clearchannel.js) if you need a working example):

```
//Get the position of the channel in the channel list
var pos = message.channel.position;

//Clear channel by cloning it, and set its position to the same position
message.channel.clone().then(c => {
    c.setPosition(pos).catch(err => console.log(err));
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

//Delete original channel
message.channel.delete(`Cleared channel.`)
```

**Explanation**

After this code executes, the original channel is cloned (creating a new channel that retains all of the permissions and settings of the original, but not the messages). Then, the original channel is deleted and the clone channel's position is set to the same position as the original channel. This creates the illusion that the channel has been cleared, and allows you to "delete" messages older than 2 weeks.

Note that the above example is intended to clear the channel that the command is executed in. If you want the command to be able to specify which channel to clear (as its first argument), you need to replace all occurrences of `message.channel` with something like `message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name == args[0])`. The same goes for if you only want to be able to clear a single, hard-coded channel. You will need to then replace all occurrences of `message.channel` with something like `message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name == "channel-name")`.

**Relevant Resources**

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=clone 
[An example from my bot](https://github.com/Cannicide/scav-bot/blob/master/commands/clearchannel.js)

Comment: Ah yea, sorry, probably should've done some further research and attempts before posting here, I'm relatively new to coding and this website so thanks for telling me. I'll try this solution and let you know if it works.

Comment: So I used the working example you provided and altered it to my server, however, when I go to run the command, I get "cannot find module ../command" in the command prompt. It's probably a really simple fix but I don't know a lot about coding.

Comment: Just remove the part of my working example that has `var Command = require("../command");` and instead use your own command handler. If you pasted every line of the linked example, then your bot is attempting to use my command handler instead of your own.